# How to share CoreML model with extension?

Tags: ios, coreml

I am sharing CoreML model with app extension. Xcode generates swift code for the model. In order to use that code in extension, I had to include same model with app extension as well. Is there a way to include model only once in the app, and use in both app and extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a shared framework in your project, which is included by the app and the extension as well. You put the model in the resource folder of the framework, and you can create the path or url to the model over the framework's bundle.

EDIT: Your generated model should find the model data automatically, if you place the generated model class in the framework, too. It creates the model url from the bundle of the class (see the generated `init`methods):

```
init(contentsOf url: URL) throws {
    self.model = try MLModel(contentsOf: url)
}
convenience override init() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: MyModel.self)
    let assetPath = bundle.url(forResource: "MyModel", withExtension:"mlmodelc")
    try! self.init(contentsOf: assetPath!)
}
```

In the case of a class from a framework, `Bundle(for: MarsHabitatPricer.self)` is the bundle of the framework. Your framework only needs to export the model's class so you can use it in the app and extension.

Also note that with the likewise generated `init(contentsOf:)`, you can load your model from *everywere* you like.

Comment: Could you clarify `you can create the path or url to the model over the framework's bundle.` ? How generated swift code will know the url?

Comment: I've extended my post.

Comment: Did you manage to make this work with a mlmodel embedded in a static library ?

Comment: No, I don‘t think that this is possible. A static library is shared at compile (link) time. But the model must be shared at running time.